# How can I create an object on the fly with AngularJS using variables?

Tags: angularjs

[Javascript object creation on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016124/javascript-object-creation-on-the-fly)

[create objects on the fly with angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577520/create-objects-on-the-fly-with-angularjs)

Ok so yes, I can create objects on the fly. But I am having a hard time implementing this into my own code. Here is what I have:

```
var holdBuilding = $scope.m1Special.Buildings;
var c = 0;
$scope.m2Info = {};

angular.forEach(holdBuilding,function(){
    if($scope.m1Special.Buildings[c].loc=="Northern"){
        alert(holdBuilding[c].name);
        $scope.m2Info=[{
            name:holdBuilding[c].name;
            link:holdBuilding[c].link;
        }];
        c++;
    };
});
```

My code seems to resemble the 1st link more than the 2nd, but the 2nd is using Angular. I think he is doing something different than me though. Or maybe I am just approaching this wrong.

When I run the code, well, the Angular breaks completely. If I comment out this section, however:

```
    $scope.m2Info=[{
        name:holdBuilding[c].name;
        link:holdBuilding[c].link;
    }];
```

Then the code runs and I am able to see that the alert does correctly alert the *names*. It just doesn't like the object building part. What am I doing wrong?

The error that I am getting when the Angular breaks is:

> SyntaxError: missing } after property list

for line:

```
name:holdBuilding[c].name;
```

Comment: Define "breaks completely".

Comment: When Angular breaks completely, it shows all the interpolations on the page. Anything from the Angular controller does not show.

Comment: And the error in the console is?

Comment: "SyntaxError: missing } after property list" for line 648 which is: `name:holdBuilding[c].name;`. Sorry I forget to check that sometimes, still don't make sense to me.

Comment: Are you trying to make a copy of all the objects in `$scope.m1Special.Buildings` that have the `loc` Northern?

Comment: @allienx Yes, because I am trying to be able to use it elsewhere in my code without using original and without recreating it. Basically, I could manually just create multiple objects, a group for "Northern" a group for "Western" etc, but I already have them created, so trying to instead essentially extract what is already there and reuse the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alt. 1:

```
$scope.m2Info.name = holdBuilding[c].name;
$scope.m2Info.link = holdBuilding[c].link;
```

You already have an object, you only need to set the properties.

Alt. 2:

```
$scope.m2Info = {
                  name: holdBuilding[c].name,
                  link: holdBuilding[c].link
                };
```

To define a new object including properties you follow the syntax `name: value,`. No comma is needed for the last property.

Comment: Marking yours as answer, turns out I just needed to replace the *semi-colons* at the ends with *comas*, ugh, hate it when I make simple stupid syntax errors. Glad to know I was otherwise doing it right!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `angular.copy` if you are replacing an entire array or object. This will update the reference to the original object.

Additionally you don't need to manually track an iterator. `angular.forEach` function contains the object as the first parameter.

```
var buildings = $scope.m1Special.Buildings;
$scope.m2Info = [];

angular.forEach(buildings, function(building) {
    if (building.loc=="Northern") {
        alert(building.name);
        angular.copy([{
            name:building.name;
            link:building.link;
        }], $scope.m2Info);
    };
});
```

It should be noted that `$scope.m2Info` will always only contain the last object in the buildings array. You may want to use `$scope.m2Info.push(building);` instead.

*Edit: you can also get the key via the second parameter in the forEach function `angular.forEach(buildings, function(building, key) {...}`*

Comment: I guess copying it is ok, there will never be a time that either object *changes* on the fly. However, how is having `$scope.m2Info` only containing the last object in the buildings array? The point of doing `angular.forEach` is to capture **all** the objects in the buildings array. Essentially yes I am trying to make a duplicate of it without copying and pasting it since I am using it elsewhere as well...but cannot use the original..

Comment: then you want to use `$scope.m2Info.push({name: building.name, link: building.link});` instead of angular.copy. Before you were explicitly overwriting the previous `$scope.m2Info` by using `$scope.m2Info= ...` (unless that line was supposed to be `$scope.m2Info[c]= ...`).

Comment: Ohh ok I get it now. Yea, with the current code, it would alert each name located in the original object if I did `alert($scope.m2Info[0].name);` so it was overriding it as you said. Changed it to $scope.m2Info[c]=...` Thanks!